# Merge multiple dictionaries by joining values in a list, when they have the same key

Tags: python

Suppose you have a list of dictionaries like in this example:

```
[{a:1, b:2},
{a:1, b:3},
{a:2, b:2}]
```

If two entries of the same key `a` have the same value in the dictionary, I want `b` to be a list of `2` and `3`:

```
[{a:1, b:[2,3]}, {a:2, b:2}]
```

Comment: You'll need to write a custom union function which takes any two dictionaries and if their keys match exactly, implement the logic which leads to your desired output. What part are you struggling with? Have you written any code?

Comment: Nothing in particular, but yesterday, i tried to wrap my head around this and was wondering, if there would be an easy solution for this.

Comment: Were you helped by any of the existing answers? Please accept one if so!

Answer (score 4):

Alright, here's a pure Python solution. Notice that the end result does not place non-collided `b` values in a `list`, which it seems like is what you want. For what it's worth, this problem becomes much easier if you allow for all `b` keys to point to lists, but to each their own.

Suppose you have this list of dictionaries:

```py
In [1]: d_list
Out[1]:
[{'a': 2, 'b': 1},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 4},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 1},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 4},
 {'a': 4, 'b': 2},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 3},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1}]
```

First, group them by the values of `a`:

```py
In [2]: groups = {}
   ...: for d in d_list:
   ...:     for key, val in d.items():
   ...:         if key == "a":
   ...:             groups[(key, val)] = groups.get((key, val), []) + [d]
   ...:

In [3]: groups
Out[3]:
{('a', 2): [{'a': 2, 'b': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4}],
 ('a', 1): [{'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1}],
 ('a', 4): [{'a': 4, 'b': 2}]}
```

Then create a `new_d_list` and iterate over each group:

```py
In [4]: new_d_list = []
   ...: for (a_key, a_val), d_list in groups.items():
   ...:     b_val = [d["b"] for d in d_list] if len(d_list) > 1 else d_list[0]["b"]
   ...:     new_d = {a_key: a_val, "b": b_val}
   ...:     new_d_list.append(new_d)
   ...:
```

Output:

```py
In [5]: new_d_list
Out[5]:
[{'a': 2, 'b': [1, 1, 4]},
 {'a': 1, 'b': [4, 3, 1]},
 {'a': 4, 'b': 2}]
```

Comment: Very nice. One way to clean it up slightly: replace `groups[(key, val)] = groups.get((key, val), []) + [d]` with `groups.setdefault((key, val), []).append(d)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

a, b = 'a', 'b'
original_list = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:3}, {a:2, b:2}]
new_list = []

for key, group in groupby(original_list, key=itemgetter(a)):
    group_list = list(group)

    if len(group_list) > 1:
        b_val = [d[b] for d in group_list]
    else:
        b_val = group_list[0]

    new_list.append({a: key, b: b_val})
```

Another possible solution would be to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a, b = 'a', 'b'
original_list = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:3}, {a:2, b:2}]
d = defaultdict(list)

for dictionary in original_list:
    d[dictionary[a]].append(dictionary[b])

new_list = [
    {a: key, b: (val if len(val) > 1 else val[0])}
    for key, val in d.items()
]
```

Comment: A very nice solution (always look in itertools first, is my usual mantra). However, it looks like this will always produce lists for `b`, but OP's desired output is that if there are no collisions in `b`, it should not be contained in a list.

Comment: @ddejohn good point. I've edited my answer to correct my mistake; thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple using `pandas` and groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
dl = [{'a':1, 'b':2},
{'a':1, 'b':3},
{'a':2, 'b':2}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dl)
df2 = df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(list).reset_index()
df2.to_dict(orient = 'records')
```

produces

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3]}, {'a': 2, 'b': [2]}]
```

### Edit

If single values should not be turned into lists then the `df2=...` line should be replaced with:

```
...
df2 = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda c:list(c) if len(c)>1 else c.iloc[0]).reset_index()
...
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this places non-collided `b` values into a list, however, OP seems to want non-collided `b` values left alone.

Comment: @ddejohn good point thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary dictionary to group the 'b' values for each 'a' value (no sorting required).  Then build your resulting list from this temporary dictionary:

```
L1 = [{'a':1, 'b':2},
     {'a':1, 'b':3},
     {'a':2, 'b':2}]

D = dict()
for d in L1: D.setdefault(d['a'],[]).append(d['b'])
L2  = [ {'a':k,'b':v if len(v)>1 else v[0]} for k,v in D.items() ]

print(L2)
[{'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3]}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2}]
```

*Note that it is generally not a good idea to have different types for the same key in regular data structures(i.e. sometimes int sometimes list) because all the code that uses that will need to make special cases of the data type. (you should have all 'b' values be lists even if some of them only have 1 item)*

Answer (score 0):

here is how `convtools` library can help you with it:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c

converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item("a"))
    .aggregate(
        {
            "a": c.item("a"),
            "b": c.ReduceFuncs.Array(c.item("b")).pipe(
                c.if_(c.call_func(len, c.this()) == 1, c.item(0), c.this())
            ),
        }
    )
    .gen_converter()
)

converter([{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 3}, {"a": 2, "b": 2}])
```